# What is the Hebrew word translated "basket" in Exodus 2:3

Tags: hebrew, exodus

What is the Hebrew word translated "basket" in Exodus 2:3 and what else is it used for in the Old Testament?

When she could hide him no longer, she took for him a **basket** made of bulrushes and daubed it with bitumen and pitch. She put the child in it and placed it among the reeds by the river bank. **([Exodus 2:3 - ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%202%3A3%20&version=ESV))**

Comment: Check biblehub or blueletterbible interliner and lexicon https://biblehub.com/exodus/2-3.htm#lexicon

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because low quality

Answer (score 1):

The Hebrew word translated in this text as "basket" (H8392: tebah / תֵּבָה) is translated in other contexts as "ark" (KJV).  Most (26) of its occurrences are associated with Noah's ark in the book of Genesis, chapters 6-9, leaving only two occurrences, once each in Exodus 2:3 and Exodus 2:5, that are used for Moses' deliverance from the river.

You may see more, courtesy of BlueLetterBible, [HERE.](https://www.blbclassic.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H8392&t=KJV)

Comment: The word is “teva,” not “teba.” There is no dagesh in the bet/vet.

Comment: @LoisTverberg The "tebah" is likely just a transliteration.  If in fact there had been a dagesh in the bet, wouldn't that have made it "tebbah"?  In any case, I just copy/pasted the English spelling of the word from BLB.  It was not intended to be the phonetic equivalent--just the spelling/transliteration. They have the _pronunciation_ as: ta·vä'.

Answer (score 0):

The Hebrew word תֵּבָה (tevah) is defined by BDB as per the appendix below.  It simply signifies a box or container.  It is only used in two instances in the OT:

- to describe Noah's "ark" of "gopher" wood
- to describe Moses' "ark" of papyrus reeds.

**APPENDIX - תֵּבָה (tevah)**

> תֵּבָה noun feminine ark (properly chest, box (compare Late Hebrew
> תֵּבָה); probably Egyptian loan-word from T-b-t, chest, coffin
> (Brugsch, ErmanZMG xlvi (1892), 123); > Babylonian word JenZA iv
> (1889), 272 f. HalJAssyr., 1888 {Nov.-Dec.}, 517); — absolute ׳ת
> Genesis 7:1 +; construct תֵּבַת Genesis 6:14; Exodus 2:3; — vessel in
> which infant Moses was laid among reeds Exodus 2:3 (made of papyrus,
> גֹּמֶא), Exodus 2:5 (both E; ᵐ5 θῖβις, θήβη, compare LewyFremdw. 100);
> vessel which saved Noah and his family, with animals, during flood (ᵐ5
> κιβωτός): Genesis 7:1,7,9,17,23; Genesis 8:6,9 (twice in verse);
> Genesis 8:10,13; Genesis 9:18 (all J), Genesis 6:14 (made of עֲצֵי
> נֹפֶר), Genesis 6:14; Genesis 6:15; Genesis 6:16; Genesis 6:16;
> Genesis 6:18; Genesis 6:19; Genesis 7:13,15,18; Genesis 8:1,4,16,19;
> Genesis 9:10 (all P).